# Settings tab with top most = true C#

Tags: c#, boolean, topmost

So I'm trying to make something and I know how to make topmost but how do I make it where from another tab like a settings tab make the main topmost but the check box is in a different tab then the one I want topmost?
here is the code I use for just being on the same tab.

```cs
if (!TopMost)
{
    TopMost = true;
}
else
{
    TopMost = false;
}
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell what exactly you're asking about.

Comment: Basically I made a new window and, I have a checkbox that says topmost and when I check it, I want it to make the main form topmost instead of the one/settings tab that the check box is on, but idk how to do that.

Comment: You need a reference to the form, e.g. when you create it store the reference in a variable, say, `myForm`. Then you can just go `myForm.TopMost = true`.

Comment: That whole block can be reduced to one line: `TopMost = !TopMost;`

Comment: I still cant really figure this out, I've tried adding a string and var but not sure